# Damaged baking result

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Im using blender 2.82 with cycles renderer and im trying to export object to unity (as fbx). Very simple one:

[image]

My problem is that after baking colors are damaged. Some areas are black (even after recalculation of normals).

This is my shader configuration:

[image]

After creating a jpg file for uv, recalculation of normals, UV Unwrap, F3->Smart UV Project->setting borders to 0.03

[image]

im trying to bake with configuration bellow:

[image]

But the result is a disaster:

[image]

What im missing?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the shader after the texture...
and i recommend to change flat to box in this case for better result
good luck (y)

Comment: Im starting my adventure :). Thanks very much 4 help !!!!